# How to generate independent(X) variable using Word2vec?

Tags: python, word2vec, sentiment-analysis

I have a movie review data set which has two columns Review(Sentences) and Sentiment(1 or 0).

I want to create a classification model using word2vec for the embedding and a CNN for the classification.

I've looked for tutorials on youtube but all they do is create vectors for every words and show me the similar words. Like this-

```
model= gensim.models.Word2Vec(cleaned_dataset, min_count = 2,  size = 100, window = 5)     
words= model.wv.vocab
simalar= model.wv.most_similar("bad")
```

I already have my dependent variable(y) which is my 'Sentiment' column all I need is the independent variable(X) which I can pass on to my CNN model.

Before using word2vec I used the Bag Of Words(BOW) model which generated a sparse matrix which was my independent(X) variable. How can I achieve something similar using word2vec?

Kindly correct me if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't fully get your question. Do you want the word vector?

Comment: I have the vector for each word. I just don't know how I can co relate those vectors for the appropriate sentiment, which is good(1) or bad(0). I will have to co relate that entire sentence with a sentiment, not a single word.

Answer (score 1):

To get the word vector, you have to do this:

```
model['word_that_you_want']
```

You may also want to handle the `KeyError` that could arise if you don't find that given word in your model. You also might want to read about what an `embedding layer` is, which is usually used as the first layer of the neural network (for NLP generally) and is basically a lookup mapping of a word to its corresponding word vector.

To get the word vectors for an entire sentence, you need to first initialize a numpy array of zeros to the dimensions you want.

You might need other variables such as the length of the longest sentence so that you can pad all sentences to that length. The documentation of the `pad_sequences` method for Keras is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences).

A simple example of getting a sentence of word vectors is:

```
import numpy as np

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_len, size_of_your_word_vector))
```

*Then iterate over the index of embedding_matrix and add to it, if you find a word vector in your model.*

I use this [resource](https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-word-embeddings-for-deep-learning-in-keras/) which has a lot of examples and I have referenced some of the code there (which I have also used myself sometimes):

```
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_length, 100))
for word, index in word_tokenizer.word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = model[word] # using your w2v model, KeyError possible
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[index] = embedding_vector
```

And in your model (I'm assuming Tensorflow with Keras)

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_length, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=length_long_sentence, trainable=False)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I need vectors for the entire sentence not a single word. For example "I loved this movie"

Comment: @Bot thank you for clarifying. I updated my answer. Let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

`Word2Vec` doesn't inherently create vectors for a text (set of words) – just individual words.

But, sometimes a not-so-bad vector for a multi-word text is the average of all its word-vectors.

If `list_of_words` is a list of the words in your text, and all the words are in the `Word2Vec` model, a simple way to get the average of those words' vectors is:

```
avg_vector_of_words = model.wv[list_of_words].mean(axis=0)
```

(If some words aren't present, you'd need to filter them before attempting this to avoid `KeyError`s. If you wanted to leave out some words, or use unit-normed word-vectors, or unit-normalize the final vector, you'd need more code.)

Then `avg_vector_of_words` is a small, dense/'embedded' feature vector for the `list_of-words` text.

You could pass these vectors, one per text, to another downstream classifier, like your CNN, exactly analogously to how you were previously using sparse BOW vectors.

Comment: This was what I was looking for